# How to change the size of input boxes in the same inline-form on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am developing a webpage using bootstrap where the user will input their personal data, like address, phone, etc. In the address, I have "Number" and "Complement" inputs in the same inline-form, and I want to make the `Number` input to be smaller then `Complement`. Right now they have the same width

My HTML:

```
<div class="form-inline" id="double_form_register">
    <div class="form-group" id="left_form_register">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Number"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complement" placeholder="Complement"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My less:

```
#left_form_register {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#double_form_register {
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 15px;       
    width: 500px;
}
```

When I set width to `#left_form_register`, it all brokes. I have experience in backend, but vey new to front-end development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use also the twitter-bootstrap grid system

```
<div class="form-inline" id="double_form_register">
   <div class="form-group col-md-2" id="left_form_register">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Number"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complement" placeholder="Complement"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: Didn't change the size. Maybe my less file is wrong?

Comment: I have update the answer (a mistake md2, md4 instead col-md-2, col-md-4

Comment: Whats happening is that the col-md-4 is over the col-md-2 div, but the size is the same. I can sse the highlight of the first behind the second

Comment: Fixed, I just needed to set input widht to 100%